# Django unable to connect postgres when dockerized

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I keep trying to connect my django container to a postgres container and it just down not want to connect. My dockerfile for my Django project

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
RUN python catconstruct/manage.py migrate
```

and my docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    hostname: 'db'
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  kittenkube:
    build: .
    command: python catconstruct/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: kk.example.org
       LETSENCRYPT_HOST: kk.example.org
       LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: kk@example.org
    expose:
      - 80
    depends_on:
      - db
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:5432"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 5

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Postgres seems to run just fine, as I can call docker-compose up db and then get into psql just fine. I added the hostname, expose, and ports parameters in an attempt to fix it, every other example online seems to just use the image parameter.

Trying to troubleshoot I mostly call docker-compose up -d db (to ensure that the db is up and running) and then call docker-compose up --build -d kittenkube which then errors out on migrate with the error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

Here are my database settings from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

I suspect that my network is what's breaking everything, but I can't really seem to find the right keywords to search for what I'm not understanding.

Comment: can you post your database settings, in settings.py file?

Comment: Updated post with the db settings.